# Pseudo code example

Tags: pseudocode

I am new to programming in general and I am trying to learn the basics of it. Could someone explain me the concept of Pseudo code. I have already done some research but an additional help would be great. As an example, what would pseudo code for making a peanut butter and jelly sandwich would look like?

-Thank you.

Comment: looks like a homework question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework questions must contain a description of what's been done so far to solve the problem and because this information is easily available on Google. Googling "what is pseudocode?" gives over 2.9 million results, including several very understandable definitions on the first page; what's wrong with those articles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pseudo code is a simplified language designed to express ideas in programming without using the syntax of a specific programming language. It is a way to express algorithms in a compact and understandable form, making it easier to discuss and understand the code without actually writing it.

Pseudo code can either consist of real code-like examples, or just pure text.

An example of a pseudo code for making a PBJ could look something like this:

```
MakePBJRoutine(input: peanut butter, jelly, bottom bread, top bread) 
Begin routine:
        Take bottom bread. 
        Spread peanut butter on bottom bread. 
        Spread jelly on bottom bread. 
        If want more jelly:
              Spread jelly on bottom bread. 
        Place top bread slice on bottom bread
        Return finished sandwich
End routine
```

Meanwhile, it could also look like this.

```
makePBJroutine(input: P, J, TB, BB; Out: PBJ) {
     BB <- P;
     BB <- J;
     If(BB.J < PreferredJellyAmountConstant){
         BB <- J;
     } 
    PBJ <- (BB <- TB);
    Return PBJ;
}
```