# How to send multiple string by stdin in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I send the string Router_Status[Router]='ON' by the parent code to new process

```
proc[Router] = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, os.getcwd() + '/'
                                + Router + '.py', Router,
                                json.dumps(graph),
                                json.dumps(As_numbers_dict)],
                                shell=False, stderr=True,
                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

proc[Router].stdin.write(bytes(Router_Status[Router],
                               encoding='utf-8') + b'\n')
```

and the child process is

```
Router_Status[Router]=sys.stdin.readline().strip()
path = os.path.expanduser('~' + '/BGP_Routers/' + Router)
with open(path + '/Router_Status.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(Router_Status[Router])
```

but it does not work!
And then  I pass the second string Router_Status[Router]='OFF' to the process by
    proc[Router].stdin.write(bytes(Router_Status[Router], encoding='utf-8')

```
proc[Router].stdin.flush()
```

and it still does not do anything!

Comment: doesn't work how? child stays stuck? Do you use `proc[Router].wait()` in your parent process or do you exit at once?

Comment: My child process has some  infinite loop subprocess  till the the child process  receive new string='OFF'. I want to send two stdin. write and read them in my child process. Also it does not generate file and does not write 'ON' or 'OFF' in file. the file path is correct.

Comment: have you tried `proc[Router].stdin.close()` ? just to see what it's doing

Comment: Yes After proc[Router].stdin.write(bytes(Router_Status[Router],encoding='utf-8') + b'\n') I write proc[Router].stdin.close() but the second time when I want to send 'OFF' it errors'ValueError: write to closed file'

Comment: `stderr=True` also looks suspicious. Can you set to `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` ?

Comment: I dont need stdout and stderr I just send two strings 'ON' and 'OFF' to script by stdin and read them in my script.

Comment: `with open(path + '/Router_Status.txt', 'wb')` I guess input is bytes you cannot write to text file.

Comment: No, when I write stdin.close() after first invoke it generates file and write 'ON' in it but for the second invoke it errors  ValueError: write to closed file'

Comment: See my answer, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I am not completely familiar with the arguments you are passing to your subprocess.Popen() so I am unable to check whether those are correct. I do however know a thing or two about the subprocess module and there are some things to consider looking at your code:

- Using `shell=False` does not need to be defined explicitly as it is the standard setting (although, if you want to make it explicit for a reason, that is allright of course).
- The argument `stderr=False` is incorrect. It must be either `None` or something like a `subprocess.PIPE`.

Then, since you are using Python3.x the docs state that:

> **Warning** - Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or
>   .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe
>   buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

So you'd be better of using `proc[Router].communicate(input="your standard input, meaning your stdin")`

It also states:

> **Popen.stdin** - If the stdin argument was PIPE, this attribute is a
>   writeable stream object as returned by open(). If the encoding or
>   errors arguments were specified or the universal_newlines argument was
>   True, the stream is a text stream, otherwise it is a byte stream. If
>   the stdin argument was not PIPE, this attribute is None.

In your case the means stdin should indeed by a byte stream.

Overal, I am guessing you should do something like:

```
proc[Router] = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, os.getcwd() + '/'
                                + Router + '.py', Router,
                                json.dumps(graph),
                                json.dumps(As_numbers_dict)],
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

proc[Router].stdin.communicate(str(Router_Status[Router]).encode())
```

I am still wondering however, why did you include:

```
path = os.path.expanduser('~' + '/BGP_Routers/' + Router)
with open(path + '/Router_Status.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(Router_Status[Router])
```

Since it is basically unrelated to the subprocess.Popen() statement. All it does is write the user input into a textfile, which will only capture the latest input btw. If you'd like to save all user input change `'w'` to `'a'` (this will put the file in append-mode instead of write-mode).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is about routers. I have to send 'ON' or 'OFF' string to script  to run it as Os of router . For example Router_statues='ON'. Then in [sys.executable, os.getcwd() + '/' + Router + '.py' I just invoke the script and pass 'ON' to it. My question is how can I read 'ON' string in my script???

Comment: Meaning you want to call the command-line: `[sys.executable, os.getcwd() + '/' + Router + '.py']` and simply pass `'ON'` as an argument? For if so why don't you try `[sys.executable, os.getcwd() + '/' + Router + '.py', 'ON']` which would do exactly that... Or do you instead mean you want to open `~/Router.py` and read its content to see if it is set to either `'ON'` or `'OFF'`?

Comment: It might help to add some [pseudo-code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41517236/4041795) to your question to clarify what you mean.. for it remains a bit vague otherwise..

Comment: I have 10 scripts which each of them is one router. [Sys.executable]command executes scripts in the [os.getcwd() + '/' + Router + '.py'] path. And each script is operating system of router.Then I have to pass argument.